# While testing with vitest in quasar, I get the error "wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on Q-INPUT"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, quasar-framework, vitest

I want to test my simple quasar application. I have a login form in my application and I want to assign values to the q-inputs I use in the login form with vitest, but I get the error "wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on Q-INPUT". I am testing a frontend project written with a framework for the first time. I'm also open to any documentation you can suggest on this subject.

**This is my login form written in pug**

```
 q-form.q-gutter-sm.q-px-lg
  .column.justify-start
    span.text-primary.text-body2.q-mb-sm
      | E-mail
    q-input#loginEmail(color="accent" v-model="credential" outlined dense lazy-rules :rules="[val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please enter your email or phone number!']")
  .column.justify-start
    span.text-primary.text-body2.q-mb-sm
      | Password
    q-input#loginPassword(color="accent" v-model="password" outlined dense lazy-rules :type="isPwd ? 'password' : 'text'" :rules="[val => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Please enter the password!']" @keyup.enter="login")
      template(v-slot:append)
        q-icon.cursor-pointer(:name="isPwd ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'" @click="isPwd = !isPwd")
  .row.justify-center
    q-btn#loginSubmit.q-mt-md.text-capitalize.text-weight-bold(rounded padding="0.75rem 5rem" color="primary" size="md" @click="login" label="Login")
```

**This is my test app**

```
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import login from '../../src/pages/login/index.vue'
import { QBtn, QInput, Quasar } from 'quasar'
import { api } from '@/plugins'

describe('login-form', () => {
  it('renders correctly', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(login, {
      global: {
        plugins: [QInput, QBtn],
        mocks: {
          $api: api,
          $q: Quasar
        }
      },
      props: {
        credential: 'test',
        password: 'test'
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.element).toMatchSnapshot()
    //find username input
    expect(wrapper.find('#loginEmail').exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find('#loginPassword').exists()).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.find('#loginSubmit').exists()).toBe(true)

    const select = wrapper.find('#loginEmail')
    await select.setValue('test')
  })
})
```

**This is the error i get that drives me crazy**

```
Error: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on Q-INPUT
 ❯ DOMWrapper.setValue node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:7493:19
 ❯ test/tests/login.test.js:29:18
     27| 
     28|     const select = wrapper.find('#loginEmail')
     29|     await select.setValue('test')
       |                  ^
     30|   })
     31| })
```